# Adding an -/+ increment to an item then totaling it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have an order page which allows the costumer to select an item and its quantity and then calculate the total amount ordered in a div.

Here's my code:

For the quantity jquery:

```
  <script> 
 $(function() {

 $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

 $(".button").on("click", function() {

var $button = $(this);
var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

if ($button.text() == "+") {
  var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + "The Price";
} else {
   // Don't allow decrementing below zero
  if (oldValue > 0) {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - "The Price";
    } else {
    newVal = 0;
  }
  }

$button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

 });

  });
```

The HTML for the items:

```
     <ul>
        <li class="numbers-row">
        <label>
        <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="combos[]" id="item2-title"  value="The Name"/>
        The Thumbnail<p>The Title</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="item1-val" value="The Price">
        </label>
        </li>

        <li class="numbers-row">
        <label>
        <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="combos[]" id="item2-title"  value="The Name"/>
        The Thumbnail<p>The Title</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="item2-val" value="The Price">
        </label>
        </li>

         <li class="numbers-row">
        <label>
        <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="combos[]" id="item2-title"  value="The Name"/>
        The Thumbnail<p>The Title</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="item2-val" value="The Price">
        </label>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

My jquery for the total:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function calcscore(){
          var score = 0;
            var checked=$(".calc:checked ~   input[type=hidden]").each(function(){
            score+=parseInt($(this).val());
            });
     $('#price').text(score.toFixed(2));
       }
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".calc").change(function(){
         calcscore()
     });
    });
     </script>
```

And my HTML where the total price of the items will be shown:

```
  <p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span></p>
```

My question how do i link all of these?

There are actually a lot more items, but for the sake of simplifying we'll stick with 3.

PS
I only basic jquery and PHP but I can copy paste to the least. Any input is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks guys

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @CesarWilliam sorry about that. it's past midnight in this part of the world and forgot to put the most important part. lol my question is how do i link the all of these? because right now it not's working.

Answer (score 0):

Well first let's correct the first part:
Don't use var all the time depending on what you want to achieve.
Use strict comparison === except you want specific behaviour.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //You could put the div in your HTML directly to avoid the need for JS interpretation
    $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

    $(".button").click(function (e) {

        var $button = $(e.target);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
        var newVal;
        if ($button.text() === "+") {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + "The Price";
        } else if ($button.text() === "-") {
            // Don't allow decrementing below zero
            newVal = oldValue > 0 ? parseFloat(oldValue) - "The Price" : 0;
        } else {
            //Handle error
        }

        $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

    });
    function calcPrice() {
        var score = 0;
        //the next declaration seems very unreadable IMHO.
        var checked = $(".calc:checked~input[type=hidden]").each(function (elem) {
            price += parseInt(elem.val());
        });
        $('#price').text(price.toFixed(2));
    }
    $(".calc").change(function () {
        calcPrice();
    });
});
```

For the second part:
I merged it with the first.
You don't have to call document.ready.
Score is a price? Then call it price! Or it becomes unreadable. Stick with camelCase as all JS developers do. Don't forget ; at the end of lines.
Also, don't forget to add jQuery library before your code.

Let me know in the comments if i can help you more. I didn't try to run this.

Comment: sorry about that. it's past midnight in this part of the world and forgot to put the most important part. lol my question is how do i link the all of these? because right now it not's working

Comment: @sp3 That is not an answer but an comment.

Comment: This will obviously becomes an aswer but there was no question on this subject at this moment so well .. You can say i t was an answer.